# clEnqueueNDRangeKernel Isn't running over full global range

Tags: opencl

I have a kernel.

```
__kernel void unprimed_grid_int(__global double *ar_u,          
                                __global double *ap_u,          
                                __global double *az_u,          
                                __global const double *x_p,     
                                __global const double *y_p,     
                                __global const double *z_p,     
                                __global const double *jx_p,    
                                __global const double *jy_p,    
                                __global const double *jz_p,    
                                const uint nr,                
                                const uint nz,                  
                                const uint nv,         
                                const double rmin,      
                                const double dr,     
                                const double zmin,      
                                const double dz,     
                                const double dv,   
                                const double dvol, 
                                const uint p_size, 
                                const uint offset) { 

    const size_t i = get_global_id(0);

    const size_t ri = (i + offset)%nr;
    const size_t zi = ((i + offset)/nr)%nz;
    const size_t vi = ((i + offset)/(nr*nz))%nv;

    const double r = ri*dr + rmin;
    const double z = zi*dz + zmin;
    const double v = vi*dv;

    const double x = r*cos(v);
    const double y = r*sin(v);

    double ax = 0.0;
    double ay = 0.0;
    double az = 0.0;

    for (uint j = 0; j < p_size; j++) {
        const double dx = x_p[j] - x;
        const double dy = y_p[j] - y;
        const double dz = z_p[j] - z;

        const double rp = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz);

        ax += jx_p[j]/rp;
        ay += jy_p[j]/rp;
        az += jz_p[j]/rp;
    }

    ax *= dvol;
    ay *= dvol;
    az *= dvol;

    ar_u[i] += x/r*ax + y/r*ay;
    ap_u[i] += -y/r*ax + x/r*ay;                               
    az_u[i] += az;                                              
}
```

That i'm calling from

```
    const size_t offset = 0;
    clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(device->queue, device->kernels["int"], 1, &offset, &device->u_chunk, NULL, static_cast<cl_uint>(wait.size()), wait.data(), &event);
```

with a global work size (`device->u_chunk`) of 734208. However the kernel, when run on my GPU, is only running over the first 2560 work items. I have checked the global work size inside the kernel by printing the value of `get_global_size(0)`. If I add a print statement to check that what items of `get_global_id(0)`, it runs over the full range.

What would cause a kernel to not run over the full range?

**Update**

To add an add an example of what's happening, here is a plot of the code output.
[image: Plot of the ap_u buffer]
As you can see the kernel did not run over the full range. To further demonstrate this, I ran the test case suggested by one of the answers. I modified my kernel to add an extra argument.

```
__kernel void unprimed_grid_int(..., __global uint *test) {
   ...
   if (get_global_id(0) == 5) { //  Reran with 5 changed to 700000
      test[0] == 10;
   }
}
```

For the global id value below where the output appears to cutoff (2560), I read back the correct value of 10. For a global id value above the cutoff, I get the incorrect value returned.

Comment: My guess is that it really is running over the whole range (your second printf proves it) but your printf of the global_size is somehow incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why my kernel wasn't operating over the full global range. The problem stems from the for loop in the kernel. `p_size` is on the order of `700000` iterations. This caused the kernel to take a long time to execute. Since my GPU's are connected to displays, [the kernel is timing out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27648360/opencl-limit-on-for-loop-size) so the [UI doesn't lock up](http://[the%20kernel%20is%20timing%20out][1]).

Answer (score 2):

I think, it actually runs over all the items, but printing all the values isn't working correctly, because there are a lot of threads.

To make sure it works, you could also add an integer variable as an argument of the kernel and do the following:

```
__kernel void unprimed_grid_int(your_arguments, int test) {

    if (get_global_id(0) == 734207) {
        test = 10; // or any other value
    }
}
```

Then, after the kernel is executed, if all the items are handled, it should be 10 or whatever number you use.

Comment: I tried this for two global id values above and below the 2560. In both cases the value of the test integer never changed.

Comment: @user1139069 did you read the value using clEnqueueReadBuffer?

Comment: I reimplemented test as a `cl_mem` object and reran. For a global id of 5, I get the correct value returned. For a global id of 700000, the value is unchanged.

Comment: clEnqueueReadBuffer works in Bytes, remember to do `size*sizeof(double)`